# Update a user property in Firebase Analytics from Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

Is it possible to update a user property in Firebase Analytics from Firebase Cloud Functions? What I'm looking for is the equivalent as Analytics.setUserProperty() in Swift.

I need to update this value in the background even if the user has not been active in the app, that's why I need it to happen in Cloud Functions.

I can't find anything about this in the docs.

Comment: there is no server-side API for Firebase Analytics.